# Android Java 8 Stream api NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, sdk, java-stream

After updting my Android Studio to 3.1 version, gradle to 4.1 version and support libraries to 27.0.1 version I can not use Stream api methods.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method of$$STATIC$$(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/stream/Stream; in class Ljava/util/stream/Stream; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.stream.Stream' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar)

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            if (mapper.getCardsArray().stream().anyMatch(mapperCard -> mapperCard.getCardHashId().equals(card.getCardHashId()))) {
                mapper.getCardsArray().stream()
                        .map(mapperCard ->
                                mapperCard.getCardHashId().equals(card.getCardHashId())
                                        ? card
                                        : mapperCard);

            } else {
                mapper.setCardsArray(
                        Stream.concat(
                                mapper.getCardsArray().stream(),
                                Stream.of(card)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            }

        }
```

Exception throwns when I try to use such methods of Stream class as Stream.concat(), Stream.of()
This is my gradle app file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    ....
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        ...
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 34
        versionName "0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            debuggable false
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '26.1.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
        jumboMode true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            ...
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    /* Support libraries */
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    /* Play services */
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'

    /* Firebase services */
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'

    /* Plugins */
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

But before updating all worked fine and when I try call these methods in Evaluate Expression in debug mode all works. Also I updated SDK platforms and tools to latest versions and removed Retrolambda dependecy from my project

Comment: Are you using this https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/ if not can you give it a try.

Comment: @sunilsunny stream support it's for sdk version less than Nougat. I check platform sdk version in if {} else {} condition

Comment: FWIW, streamsupport could still be used on Nougat / Oreo and a lot of apps do that in order to avoid having to maintain different code bases for pre-24 and API level >= 24 devices. streamsupport by default even delegates to the native Android implementation when it is run on a API >= 24 device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else faced with a similar problem, just restore retrolamda dependecy in gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
    }
}
```

and add the following line into module app build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

Ignore Android Studio warning: "One of the plugins you are using supports Java 8 language features. To try the support built into the Android plugin, remove the following from your build.gradle: apply plugin:'me.tatarka.retrolambda'"

Comment: "To try the support built into the Android plugin ..." And then happens what? Do you again get `NoSuchMethodError` or does it work then?

Comment: @Sartorius when I removed retrolambda plugin I get NoSuchMethod error when invoke stream api methods